# Passing variables to another class via Intent and Adapter

Tags: android, android-intent, adapter

I'm trying to pass a bunch of variables to another Activity, 
but in the receiving Activity it only got access to the first element.

My listView1 contains 3 Elements: a 2 TextViews and 1 ImageView...

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(),
                    DisplayListEntry.class);

            intent.putExtra("TOPIC",    listView1.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString());

            startActivityForResult(intent,   0);
```

Receiving Activity:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent(); 

    String s1 =  intent.getStringExtra("TOPIC");
```

And i want to access them via the Intent...
Could somebody please be so kind and tell me how its done? :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are sending only single item in your intent as extra

Comment: Bunch of variables means? object?

Comment: I fail to see where you try to pass the _bunch_ of values?

Comment: My listView1 contains 3 Elements: 2 TextViews and 1 ImageView...
and i dont know how to access them :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you have three views and want to these data to another activity.

The first problem is you are starting another activity inside the onItemClick and at this point, you are using the item position to get current value. That is ok, but you are only getting a value for one specific view, whose is being clicked.
    listView1.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();

If you really want to pass the three values my suggestion is:

- Create a field on your class for each view

Ex: 
      Textview t1, t2;
      ImageView i1;

And onClick event you will use it to put inside the intent like that:

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), DisplayListEntry.class);

        intent.putExtra("key1",t1.getText());
        intent.putExtra("key2",t2.getText());
        intent.putExtra("key3",i2.get***());

        startActivityForResult(intent,   0);
```

In you another activity you can access those values:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent(); 
 String s1 =  intent.getStringExtra("key1"); 
 String s2 =  intent.getStringExtra("key2"); 
 ***     =  intent.get****("key3");
```

You should change *** for the data type you want to pass.

Comment: Actually that did it for me :) thx alot :)

I was already using an array with data. The mystake was to think that i can easily acces all data via the listview1.

Thx Again :)

Answer (score 0):

you can Add PutExtra as many as you want with different key and position of your item and in another class get it using key.

Comment: and use getIntent().getExtras(); to get it back

Answer (score 0):

First you need to correct in this in next activity

```
 Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if( b != null ){
        String s1 =  intent.getStringExtra("TOPIC"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = getIntent();

```
String s1 =  intent.getStringExtra("TOPIC");
```

here you s1 declare as string..

it will not work because there are u pass arraylist.....

declare arraylist variable and try to implement it..